# Compare an array to several numbers at once

Tags: matlab

How do you compare an array of numbers to several given numbers? More precisely, I have an array given like so

```
inputArray = [1 2 2 3 4 6]
```

and I want to compare inputArray to the numbers 1:7 to ultimately count how many times a "1" is in inputArray, a "2", a "3" and so on.

Obviously I can do something like

```
res = zeros(7,1);
for i = 1:7
   res(i) = sum(inputArray == i);
end
```

or more generally when I also might be interested in the locations of occurrences

```
res = zeros(7,length(inputArray));
for i = 1:7
   res(i,:) = inputArray == i;
end
res2 = sum(res,1);
```

Out of curiosity and/or speed improvements I am wondering if this is possible without a for loop in a single statement?

Comment: If the array is always sorted then optimisations are possible.

Comment: @Bathsheba The array can always be sorted (with low complexity) so optimizations should always be possible.

Comment: Complexity of sort is higher than the complexity of traversal O(N). So I doubt that pre-sorting is ever a wise thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a histogram count, see here:

```
x = [1 3 10 1 8]
b = [1 2 3]
histc(x,b)
```

Will produce

```
[2 0 1]
```

Comment: oh, yes, I did not realize! I am aware of the histc function, but did not think of it in this context. With the second output of histc also the occurences of x or "inputArray" can be stored.

Answer (score 2):

When you want more dimensions of vectorization than is built in to the functions you're working with, or want to collapse a simple loop into a function call, you can use `bsxfun` ("Binary Singleton eXpansion FUNction"). It's pretty general, reasonably fast, and produces concise code.

In this case, you could use it to construct that equality grid, and then sum them up.

```
a = [1 2 2 3 4 5];
i = [1:7]';  % Flip it so it's oriented perpendicular to a
res = bsxfun(@eq, a, i);
counts = sum(res,2)';  %'

% One-liner version
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq, a, [1:7]'), 2)';
```

Though in the particular case you're working with, since you're doing simple arithmetic operations on primitive arrays, the `for` loops might actually be fastest with JIT optimizations, as long as you're careful to isolate the work in its own function so the JIT can do "in-place" optimizations.

Comment: Nice, thanks! This is pretty much the first time I heard about JIT. Read this article http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/ but still do not really now, what you mean by "as long as you are careful to isolate the work...". Could you clarify?

Comment: Yeah... to have the best chance of the JIT optimizing loops over primitive arrays, create a small function to do just that work, and make sure it does not pass the arrays you're working on as arguments to any regular (non-builtin) function from there. Basically, just use the arithmetic and relational operators and for/while loops inside that function; don't make any other function calls from there that use those arrays as arguments. It seems like if the arrays "escape" that function before it returns, the JIT can't do in-place optimizations on them. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility: use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
count = accumarray(inputArray(:), 1, [7 1]); %// Change "7" as needed
```